# Prevent webpack from auto-incrementing project version

Tags: node.js, webpack, google-chrome-extension, webpack-4

I am working with a chrome extension which uses webpack to build.

To build I use this : `cross-env NODE_ENV=production yarn webpack -c webpack.config.js --mode production`

webpack.config.js

```
const HTMLPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const BrowserExtensionPlugin = require("extension-build-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    options: './src/options.tsx',
    popup: './src/popup.tsx',
    content: './src/content.tsx',
    background: './src/background.tsx',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.css'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    alias: {
      react: 'preact/compat',
      'react-dom': 'preact/compat',
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(tsx|jsx|ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                "@babel/preset-react",
                "@babel/preset-typescript",
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLPlugin({
      chunks: ['options'],
      filename: 'options.html',
      title: 'Options page title',
    }),
    new HTMLPlugin({
      chunks: ['popup'],
      filename: 'popup.html',
    }),
    new CopyPlugin([
      { from: './src/_locales/', to: './_locales' },
      { from: './src/assets', to: './assets' },
      { from: './src/manifest.json', to: './manifest.json' },
    ]),
    new BrowserExtensionPlugin({devMode: false, name: "build/chromium.zip", directory: "src", updateType: "minor"}),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJSPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            drop_debugger: true,
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  },
  mode: 'production',
  stats: 'minimal',
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000
  }
};
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "__MSG_appName__",
    "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    ....
    ....
}
```

If I run `cross-env NODE_ENV=production yarn webpack -c webpack.config.js --mode production` again it increments the `version` from  `0.1.0` to   `0.2.0` automatically not just in `build` folder but in `src` folder as well. How can I prevent this auto increment functionality.
I suspect it's due to one of the webpack plugins I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by [`extension-build-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/Jasmin2895/extension-build-webpack-plugin#-webpack-plugin-for-extension-build) which you really shouldn't have struggled to find, as there's a total of 4 plugins there to look at.

No, it does not offer any method of avoiding version bumps. You can only [configure if you want it to bump the major or minor version number, defaulting to minor](https://github.com/Jasmin2895/extension-build-webpack-plugin#custom-options).

It's a really weird library to be using, it gets few downloads and is unmaintained. There's probably better alternatives out there.

Comment: its surprising `updateType: none` is not an option. People may need to build multiple times for testing. Anyways thanks.

Comment: btw what plugin do you suggest for zipping the build?